# WordPress Sub Menu - Show On Hover

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I have a WordPress site set up with some navigation.  Each of the parent nav links contains sub menus.

What I want to do in psuedoish code is as follows:

- If current page, then show current page sub menu;

BUT

- Even if current page, if another parent link is hovered on then show that sub menu instead.  Once hover state no longer exists, revert to current page sub menu.

At the moment I have this:

JQUERY

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $(".sub-menu").hide();
    $(".current_page_item .sub-menu").show();
    });
    </script>
```

This successfully shows the current pages sub menu for all pages but I can't work out how to show another sub menu if it's parent link is hovered upon.

The sub menu occupies exactly the same space so upon a hover it should hide the current pages sub menu links.

Can someone please help.

Thanks in advance.

HTML

```
    <li id="menu-item-30" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-30"><a href="http://localhost:81/pps/">Home</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-34" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-16 current_page_item menu-item-34"><a href="http://localhost:81/pps/?page_id=16">Our Services</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu" style="display: block;">
        <li id="menu-item-36" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-36"><a href="http://localhost:81/pps/?page_id=18">Services Sub Page One</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-37" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-37"><a href="http://localhost:81/pps/?page_id=20">Services Sub Page Two</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-35" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-35 no-cross"><a href="http://localhost:81/pps/?page_id=22">Services Sub Page Three</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-38" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-38"><a href="http://localhost:81/pps/?page_id=24">Why Us?</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu" style="display: block;">
        <li id="menu-item-46" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-46"><a href="http://localhost:81/pps/?page_id=44">Subpage of Why Us?</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-50" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-50 no-cross"><a href="http://localhost:81/pps/?page_id=48">Another Subpage Of Why Us?</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: you should post an example of your menus html.  Not sure what youre structure is but my first guess was the default wp_nav_menu one.  Either way, post it.

Comment: try this `$( "li.menu-item" ).hover(function() {
$( this ).find( ".sub-menu" ).show();
});`

Comment: @Rooster have added the html code.

Comment: @StreetCoder this has a weird effect.  If I hover on the second parent then the sub-menu appears for that parent, and likewise for the third.  However in the non-hover state, the current page sub-menu is no longer shown and then the last parent's sub menu is constantly displayed regardless of any further hovers on parent links.

Comment: just could you place in jsfiddle please

Comment: here's the fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/F2fGV/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's what you're looking for:

```
$( "li.menu-item" ).hover(function() {  // mouse enter
    $( this ).find( " > .sub-menu" ).show(); // display immediate child

}, function(){ // mouse leave
    if ( !$(this).hasClass("current_page_item") ) {  // check if current page
        $( this ).find( ".sub-menu" ).hide(); // hide if not current page
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks very much. That is very close but if I hover on the current pages parent and then away again, the subnav disappears altogether when there is no hover state.  The current pages sub menu should display if there is no hover state as it currently does when the page is first loaded.

Comment: Sorry, there was an erroneous `.` before `current_page_item`. See updated above and fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/k8rSn/1/

Comment: Damn, I just spotted that too.  Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

I accomplished this on the twenty-fifteen them with some Additional CSS on the theme. This might work for other themes too.

It basically hides sub-menus by default, then when the parent menu item is hovered, it displays the menu.

Add to your theme's Additional CSS:

```
/*make the menu sub-menu items drop down on mouse hover */
ul.sub-menu{ display: none; }

ul.menu li.menu-item-has-children:hover > ul.sub-menu{
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use a bootstrap-based theme add the following CSS:

```
ul.navbar-nav li.menu-item-has-children:hover > ul.dropdown-menu{
    display: block !important;
}
```

"display none" is not needed